# how to play an audio file which is in remote location in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, audio-streaming

In my windows phone 8 application, I am getting the audio file path (which is in a remote location). Now I want to play that audio file when user clicks on the button. That is nothing but how to stream the audio file.

I am new to windows phone 8 development. Please share your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MediaElement` class in Silverlight Windows Phone applications to play audio from a URI (including remote URLs)

Take a look at it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(VS.95).aspx